# How to use ant to extract all substring in a file without using regex

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have a file has many lines such as:

```
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eeee
a111 b111 c111 d111
A222 B222 X222 Y222 Z222
FFF  GGG  HHH
```

etc

I hope to use ant to extract all substring in this file

```
aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eeee
a111 b111 c111 d111
A222 B222 X222 Y222 Z222
FFF  GGG  HHH
```

in each line, ie 
all aaa bbb ccc ddd eee in 1st line,
all FFF GGG HHH in last line etc

Pls help how to do it but not using regex???

My code is:

```
<for list="@{line}"  delimiter=" " param = "val">
                <sequential>
                    <echo>in sequential : @{line}</echo>
                        <var name="first.part" value="1"/>
                        <var name="second.part" value="2"/>
                        <var name="third.part" value="3"/>
                        <propertyregex
                            property="first.part"
                            input="@{line}"
                            select="\0"/>
                        <propertyregex
                            property="second.part"
                            input="@{line}"
                            select="\1"/>
                        <propertyregex
                            property="third.part"
                            input="@{line}"
                            select="\2"/>
                        <echo> after assign: 1st.part = ${first.part}</echo>
                        <echo> after assign: 2nd.part = ${second.part}</echo>
                        <echo> after assign: 3rd.part = ${third.part}</echo>
            </sequential>

</for>
```

But ant 1.6 did not support regex, 
I got error:
The  type doesn't support the "regex" attribute.

how to fix it???
Thanks

Comment: ANT 1.6 was released in 2003.... ANT 1.7 replaced it in 2006 and introduced significant changes. I would highly recommend an upgrade

Answer (score 1):

ANT is not a programming language. You are best advised to embed one.

The following example uses [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task):

```
<project name="demo" default="scan">

    <target name="bootstrap">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.1.3/groovy-all-2.1.3.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="scan">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>
        <groovy>
        new File("File1.txt").eachLine {
            def values = it.split()

            ant.echo "Extracted values: ${values}"

            values.each {
                ant.echo "Need to so something with ${it}"
            }
        }
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```

Produces the following output

```
scan:
     [echo] Extracted values: [aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eeee]
     [echo] Need to so something with aaa
     [echo] Need to so something with bbb
     [echo] Need to so something with ccc
     [echo] Need to so something with ddd
     [echo] Need to so something with eeee
     [echo] Extracted values: [a111, b111, c111, d111]
     [echo] Need to so something with a111
     [echo] Need to so something with b111
     [echo] Need to so something with c111
     [echo] Need to so something with d111
     [echo] Extracted values: [A222, B222, X222, Y222, Z222]
     [echo] Need to so something with A222
     [echo] Need to so something with B222
     [echo] Need to so something with X222
     [echo] Need to so something with Y222
     [echo] Need to so something with Z222
     [echo] Extracted values: [FFF, GGG, HHH]
     [echo] Need to so something with FFF
     [echo] Need to so something with GGG
     [echo] Need to so something with HHH
```

## Update

An alternative way to enable the groovy task is to use a classpath reference as follows:

```
<path id="build.path">
    <pathelement location="/path/to/groovy-all/jar/groovy-all-2.1.3.jar"/>
</path>

<taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>
```

Comment: I downloaded groovy-all-2.1.3.jar and put into classpath. test your code: C:\ant\build>ant  -f buildx.xml
Buildfile: buildx.xml

scan:

BUILD FAILED
C:\ant\build\buildx.xml:9: Could not create task or type of type: groovy.

Ant could not find the task or a class this task relies upon.

This is common and has a number of causes; the usual
solutions are to read the manual pages then download and
install needed JAR files, or fix the build file:

Comment: @dateboyTom Run the "bootstrap" target first (ant bootstrap). I created this target to make it easy to configure build to use groovy. Have a look at the code, what it is doing is downloading the groovy jar and putting it into a location that will be accessible to ANT's next run. (Something similar to how you enabled the "for" task. This requires the 3rd party ant-contib.jar file which is not delivered with ANT by default).

Comment: I add:   <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
   <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${BaseDir}${fldrSepChar}tpcl${fldrSepChar}${traVersion}${fldrSepChar}ant${fldrSepChar}1.6${fldrSepChar}lib${fldrSepChar}ant-contrib.jar"/>
   </classpath>
  </taskdef>  in buildx.mail, run,     C:\ant\build>ant run   -f  buildx.xml
Buildfile: C:\ant\build\buildx.xml

run:

BUILD FAILED

Comment: @dateboyTom The groovy task is *not* part of ant-contrib. This would explain the "Could not create" errors you are getting. My answer provided a complete working example. Run the bootstrap target (i.e type "ant bootstrap") and it will download the groovy jar from Maven Central, placing it into a location that ANT uses for the storage of 3rd party task jars.